# document.body.appendChild in place where the JS is included

Tags: javascript

I want to append element after the`<script>` element that creates the element. It is for http://guubo.com/ multi-share service, so the purpose of the code is to create IFRAME element-button.

```
guubo           = new Object();

// create iframe
guubo.iframe    = document.createElement('iframe');

guubo.iframe.setAttribute('style', 'border:none; overflow:hidden; width: 93px; height: 32px;');
guubo.iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no');
guubo.iframe.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');
guubo.iframe.setAttribute('allowTransparency', 'true');

document.body.appendChild(guubo.iframe);
```

How to  append the `guubo.iframe` element after the `<script>` that runs this code? Note that there can be multiple `<script>` with the same URL on the page, therefore searching for a script element with same URL and appending after it is not an option.

Comment: `appendChild` appends to the end of the children list, therefore it will appear last. I fail to see why you'd want it right after the script running it, since it has no real stylistic significance.

Comment: Because the button has to appear in place where the `<script>` is included.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to insert an `iframe` right after the `script` element containing the code, I think selecting the last script element processed so far [by the browser/dom engine] and appending after will do the trick, however this might not always result in the desired effect, because of how different browsers load the resources in a page.

Also, you can use `var guubo = {};` instead of `guubo = new Object();`.

Comment: How do I get the last processed `script` element?

Comment: `var els = document.getElementsByTagName('script'); els[els.length-1];` However you will be better of using [inti](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6264570/document-body-appendchild-in-place-where-the-js-is-included/6264749#6264749)'s solution.

Answer (score 0):

To do this there is the old dirty method to use document.write() to place the html code where the script is. But if you want to do this the other way, you need a reference point in the document. Usually something like this:

```
<div id="guubo_btn"></div>
<script>
   /* Your script */
   document.getElemenytById("guubo_btn").appendChild(guubo.iframe);
</script>
```

This would place it actually before the scipt tag, but the result is the same.

**Edit:** the document.write() method, with only the iframe

```
var guubo   = {};

guubo.iframe_id = "ifr"+Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);

// create iframe
var iframe  = '<iframe ';
iframe += 'style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width: 93px; height: 32px;" ';
ifarme += 'id="'+guubo.iframe_id+'" ';
iframe += 'scrolling="no" ';
iframe += 'frameborder="0" ';
iframe += 'allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
document.write(iframe);

guubo.iframe = document.getElementById(guubo.iframe_id);
```

**Edit 2:** now you have the iframe in guubo object.

Comment: Well... 1st if you use document.write() you can write the iframe, no need for the div. 2nd don't use document.write() with the div, just add a div above your script tag in HTML. But, yes, your solution might work.

Comment: If I simply do `ducument.write(guubo.iframe)` I get `[object HTMLIFrameElement]`. Is there something I am missing?

Comment: You have to give document.write() the actual HTML code you want to display. Added this to my answer. Btw `src` attribute is not set in your iframe.

Comment: Well, that is the problem. I cannot simply pass the HTML because I later modify the element. See http://guubo.com/share.php

Comment: Edited my code, so it does what you need. But your first attempt with adding the div with document.write() andd appending the iframe to it was also a good approach. I wanted to explain my idea, but after seeing your full code, it was much easier to understand your goal.